# opening a target blank page with the parent page in front

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am simply creating an HTML page, where I am using `target=""` in the link which opens up the page as `target="_blank"`.

**For Instance,**

```
<a href="#" target="abc">link</a>
```

What I want is, when the user clicks on it, the blank page, which opens up, should open, but the main page from where the link is clicked should stay. Right now, it is acting like `"target="_blank"`, which onclick shows the page redirected.

Is this possible ?

Comment: So, you want to open a new page in the background?

Comment: Yes @Cerbrus .. A page, which opens like `"target=_blank"` on the new tab, but the main page from where it opened should stay.

Comment: You can't "force" browser behavior like that. Browsers have their own settings on what to do with newly opened pages.

Comment: I agree @Cerbrus, but I need that to work, as I am opening up a player which plays music, so dont want the users to see that page, as that will open only on click.

Comment: You can try <iframe> to show embedded page.

Comment: I just told you you can't do that. As in: _"It's not possible"_...

Comment: @Cerbrus , Do u really think its impossible ?

Comment: So how can this be done @Cerbrus ?? As I have seen a lot of sites having such popups, where, you click on some link and it opens up a new page on background.

Comment: could you show some example @Danyu ??

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer to this problem but you can do a nasty trick to make it look so by opening the current page in new tab and loading the link in current tab.  One disadvantage with this would be that current page will be in a tab next to new page.

You can do something like

```
<a href="https://google.com" onclick="window.open('#','_blank');window.open(this.href,'_self');">
```

I don't think you can control the browser behavior by manipulating which tab to focus,  it is like letting me make changes to your bank profile information illegally.  There is really nothing much you can do about it.